# How to connect & run Strophe JS files with Openfire Server?

Tags: xmpp, openfire, strophe, strophe.js

I have installed Openfire successfully & enabled HTTP Binding at port 7070. I have downloaded strophe.js library https://github.com/strophe/strophejs & want to run its examples, but I don't know how to connect this two. Where should I place my strophe.js files, so that it runs from Openfire server, and I even want to know how to run NodeJS code after installing NodeJS plugins in Openfire.